# How to trigger email after last modified but within business hours

Tags: workflow, case, process, businesshours

I have Business Hours enabled in my org.

I have created a process builder which triggers an email 24 hours after last modified date of a particular case. However I am not being able to understand how to incorporate the Business Hours within that or if it is at all possible.If not then is it possible by an workflow?  I am fairly new in Salesforce and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to incorporate Business Hours with the case in a configurable way, this relationship will help you.

[image: Case Business Hour]

> 1. Enable Entitlement and define Entitlement Process.

[image: Entitlement Process]

> 2. Create Entitlement Record.

[image: Entitlement Detail]

> 3. Entitlement has Master-Detail relationship to Account.

So, when a Case is created under an Account for which Entitlement record is defined, Case will be linked to the Entitlement.

By the way, Milestones can be defined under Entitlement Process and Case can be tracked with Milestones. All the Milestone dates respects Business Hours.

Answer (score 1):

If the email is being sent internally to a specified user or to the case owner, I would look at escalation rules as they allow you to send an email, can honor business hours, and can calculate age based on last modified date.

See [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rules_escalation_rule_entry.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for details.

If the email is to be sent externally, I think you need to dig into milestones and entitlements as Santanu suggests.  It appears that workflow and process builder do not factor business hours in at present (there is an [idea that is under review for it](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpq3AAC))